# Difference between (long)value and Convert.ToInt64(value)

Tags: c#, casting, dataset, long-integer

I've a procedure that gets value from database to a dataset and then copy it to a local `long typed` variable. It always contains `long value`.

This is how I'm copying value from dataset to variable.

```
AreaId = dsTable.SearchedTable[I].IsAreaIdNull() ? 0 : (long)dsTable.SearchedTable[I]["AreaId"];
```

Sometimes it works fine but sometimes it gives me error

> specific cast is not valid

then I have to change all these kind of conversion to this format

```
 AreaId = dsTable.SearchedTable[I].IsAreaIdNull() ? 0 : Convert.ToInt64(dsTable.SearchedTable[I]["AreaId"]);
```

I'm confused that what's wrong with **(long)** when it has same value for both methods and its **65**. What I'm missing over here??

Comment: It would be useful to add the language concerned to the tags.

Comment: @OskarHýbl its C#. tag added

Comment: When casting from one value type to another, the explicit defined operator is determined at compile time, but if you have an object, there is no way of knowing what casting operator to apply. If the value is a long everything is ok, Otherwise you should either cast to the specific type or use `Convert.ToInt64`. In your case, the returned value might be down-sized to a 'normal' int along the path of retrieval somewhere. This can happen in numerous situations. Say a join/coalesce/isnull sql method for example.

Comment: but it is working fine with other values. Even for this specific case, sometimes it works fine and sometime it gives error *for same data*

Comment: Buffer the value in an `object` before casting and put an `assert` there. `Debug.Assert(obj is long, "so long long");`

Comment: @NullPointer `dsTable.SearchedTable[I]["AreaId"]` might be something that always could be casted as `long` but its type is obviously not `long`. what is its type?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani its type is also long.